# How to create a list of variables per inventory host in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have following situation.
I have inventory like this (limited to relevant information):

```yaml
[management]
management-1 vhost_ip=10.0.0.1

[database]
db-1 vhost_ip=10.0.1.1
db-2 vhost_ip=10.0.1.2

[application]
app-1 vhost_ip=10.0.2.1
app-2 vhost_ip=10.0.2.2
```

Now I need to create a play like this:

```yaml
- name: Setup management server
  hosts: management
  become: true
  roles:
    - management
      database_ips:
        - 10.0.1.1
        - 10.0.1.1
      application_ips:
        - 10.0.2.1
        - 10.0.2.1
```

As you can see my management role need a list of all IPs grouped by role.
I do have those IPs already available inside my inventory.

Is there any way to do a conversion that will extract those IPs and turn them into a list? So I could call it something like this (pseudocode based on laravels higher order lists):

```
  roles:
    - management
      database_ips: {{ groups['databse']->map->vhost_ip }}
      application_ips: {{ groups['application']->map->vhost_ip }}
```

Also is it possible to do something similar but with a more complex format like this (mapping `vhost_ip` from inventory to `ip` in parameter and `alias` from inventory to `name` in parameter):

```
  roles:
    - management
      database_hosts:
        - name: db-1
          ip: 10.0.1.1
        - name: db-2
          ip: 10.0.1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty easy to achieve with the right set of filters applied to the [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `hostvars`.

The set of filter we want to apply are:

- [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) so we can make a list of the `hostvars` dictionary in order to filter on it
- [`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr) in order to filter the nodes that are in a specific, with another special variables, `groups`
- And finally a [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) to extract one attribute from each dictionary into a simple list

So, we end up with those variables:

```yaml
application_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.application) 
    | map(attribute='value.vhost_ip')
  }} 
database_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.database) 
    | map(attribute='value.vhost_ip')
  }}
management_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.management) 
    | map(attribute='value.vhost_ip')
  }}
```

---

As for the *more complex requirement*, you can use a [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) and a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org) query.

```yaml
application_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.application) 
    | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
  }} 
database_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.database) 
    | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
  }}
management_ips: >-
  {{
    hostvars  
    | dict2items 
    | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.management) 
    | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
  }}
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 
          application_ips: "{{ application_ips }}"
          database_ips: "{{ database_ips }}"
          management_ips: "{{ management_ips }}"
      vars:
        application_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.application) 
            | map(attribute="value.vhost_ip")
          }} 
        database_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.database) 
            | map(attribute="value.vhost_ip")
          }}
        management_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.management) 
            | map(attribute="value.vhost_ip")
          }}
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

    - debug:
        msg: 
          application_ips: "{{ application_ips }}"
          database_ips: "{{ database_ips }}"
          management_ips: "{{ management_ips }}"
      vars:
        application_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.application) 
            | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
          }} 
        database_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.database) 
            | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
          }}
        management_ips: >-
          {{
            hostvars  
            | dict2items 
            | selectattr('key', 'in', groups.management) 
            | json_query('[].{name: key, ip: value.vhost_ip}')
          }}
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [node2 -> localhost] => 
  msg:
    application_ips:
    - 10.0.2.1
    - 10.0.2.2
    database_ips:
    - 10.0.1.1
    - 10.0.1.2
    management_ips:
    - 10.0.0.1

TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [node2 -> localhost] => 
  msg:
    application_ips:
    - ip: 10.0.2.1
      name: app-1
    - ip: 10.0.2.2
      name: app-2
    database_ips:
    - ip: 10.0.1.1
      name: db-1
    - ip: 10.0.1.2
      name: db-2
    management_ips:
    - ip: 10.0.0.1
      name: management-1
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Use the utility *ansible-inventory*

```yaml
  my_inventory: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_inventory:
    all:
      children:
        application:
          hosts:
            app-1:
              vhost_ip: 10.0.2.1
            app-2:
              vhost_ip: 10.0.2.2
        database:
          hosts:
            db-1:
              vhost_ip: 10.0.1.1
            db-2:
              vhost_ip: 10.0.1.2
        management:
          hosts:
            management-1:
              vhost_ip: 10.0.0.1
        ungrouped: {}
```

Declare the lists

```yaml
  database_ips: "{{ my_inventory.all.children.database.hosts|json_query('*.vhost_ip') }}"
  application_ips: "{{ my_inventory.all.children.application.hosts|json_query('*.vhost_ip') }}"
```

give

```yaml
  database_ips: ['10.0.1.1', '10.0.1.2']
  application_ips: ['10.0.2.1', '10.0.2.2']
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_inventory: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --yaml')|from_yaml }}"
    database_ips: "{{ my_inventory.all.children.database.hosts|json_query('*.vhost_ip') }}"
    application_ips: "{{ my_inventory.all.children.application.hosts|json_query('*.vhost_ip') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_inventory
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: |
          database_ips: {{ database_ips }}
          application_ips: {{ application_ips }}
      run_once: true
```

---

**Original**

Iterate the groups and create a dictionary

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      d1: "{{ d1|d({})|
              combine({item: dict(_keys|zip(_vals))}) }}"
    loop: "{{ groups.keys()|list|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
    vars:
      _keys: "{{ groups[item] }}"
      _vals: "{{ groups[item]|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'vhost_ip')|
                 list }}"
    run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  d1:
    application:
      app-1: 10.0.2.1
      app-2: 10.0.2.2
    database:
      db-1: 10.0.1.1
      db-2: 10.0.1.2
    management:
      management-1: 10.0.0.1
```

The selection of the lists is trivial now

```yaml
  database_ips: "{{ d1.database.values()|list }}"
  application_ips: "{{ d1.application.values()|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  database_ips:
    - 10.0.1.1
    - 10.0.1.2

  application_ips:
    - 10.0.2.1
    - 10.0.2.2
```

The dictionary *d1* can be also used to create the variable *database_hosts*

```yaml
  database_hosts: "{{ d1.database|
                      dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='ip') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  database_hosts:
    - ip: 10.0.1.1
      name: db-1
    - ip: 10.0.1.2
      name: db-2
```

Convert the dictionaries into lists if you want to

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      d2: "{{ d2|d({})|
              combine({item: dict(_keys|zip(_vals))|
                             dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='ip')}) }}"
    loop: "{{ groups.keys()|list|difference(['all', 'ungrouped']) }}"
    vars:
      _keys: "{{ groups[item] }}"
      _vals: "{{ groups[item]|
                 map('extract', hostvars, 'vhost_ip')|
                 list }}"
    run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  d2:
    application:
      - ip: 10.0.2.1
        name: app-1
      - ip: 10.0.2.2
        name: app-2
    database:
      - ip: 10.0.1.1
        name: db-1
      - ip: 10.0.1.2
        name: db-2
    management:
      - ip: 10.0.0.1
        name: management-1
```

The usage is trivial

```yaml
  roles:
    - management
      database_hosts: "{{ d2.database }}"
```

The dictionary *d2* can be also used to create the lists if necessary

```yaml
  database_ips: "{{ d2.database|map(attribute='ip')|list }}"
  application_ips: "{{ d2.application|map(attribute='ip')|list }}"
```

---

**Note**

You can keep the default groups *all* and *ungrouped*

```yaml
          loop: "{{ groups.keys()|list }}"
```

You'll get

```yaml
  d1:
    all:
      app-1: 10.0.2.1
      app-2: 10.0.2.2
      db-1: 10.0.1.1
      db-2: 10.0.1.2
      management-1: 10.0.0.1
    application:
      app-1: 10.0.2.1
      app-2: 10.0.2.2
    database:
      db-1: 10.0.1.1
      db-2: 10.0.1.2
    management:
      management-1: 10.0.0.1
    ungrouped: {}
```

```yaml
  d2:
    all:
    - ip: 10.0.0.1
      name: management-1
    - ip: 10.0.1.1
      name: db-1
    - ip: 10.0.1.2
      name: db-2
    - ip: 10.0.2.1
      name: app-1
    - ip: 10.0.2.2
      name: app-2
    application:
    - ip: 10.0.2.1
      name: app-1
    - ip: 10.0.2.2
      name: app-2
    database:
    - ip: 10.0.1.1
      name: db-1
    - ip: 10.0.1.2
      name: db-2
    management:
    - ip: 10.0.0.1
      name: management-1
    ungrouped: []
```